# Is this really a high-quality answer?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed this review the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6511914

From what I can tell, this doesn't seem to answer the question. It doesn't provide any insight into what to DO, it is just a picture and a comment on another answer.

I gave this a poor review and was punished for it. It may have a 11 upvotes, but it doesn't really seem like a high quality post to me.

I assume SO rates posts as "High Quality" just because they're well-upvoted, they're not hand-picked.

Is this just a fluke? Is there anything to be done about this situation? My review timeout has already expired, but I wanted to present this for discussion.

Comment: Ugh. Text in an image. A picture is worth 1000 words, but parsing a picture for the search function is worth a thousand (unwritten) lines of code. This is a fluke, and I wouldn't call this an answer.

Comment: It looks like the answer has been rightfully deleted now. Sucks about the audit, though.

Comment: Makes you wonder how an "answer" like that can get 11 upvotes...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Lots of views from people who don't understand our site. It's a month old and already has 2600 views.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables All the colors!

Comment: @Compass: Did you look at it in context?  The search function will find the original answer.  But the image looks helpful, the "Source tab" referred to in the original answer doesn't use the normal tab widget.  The image is not about the text inside, but the UI layout.

Comment: I fail to see the need for these audits/tests, especially if they are so likely to fail. (I had a similiar case the other day as well, but wasn't banned: I disagreed with others about the usefulness of a post.) Even if flagging, I don't get an audit - instead, I have a limited flag count. And I am not the only one whose desicion counts - there are others as well, so I cannot really destroy anything so easy.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, it isn't high-quality. It's a very terrible answer that only attempts to reply to the other answer with an image of where they're located. It's been deleted now.

Even if you fail an audit, you can still go back to the post and flag it appropriately. In a case like this, you might as well just cast a custom flag. Casting a not an answer flag will send it to Low Quality Posts where I have no doubt reviewers would recommend deletion, but having a positive score it would not be automatically deleted and would end up in our disputed reviews list anyways. Just describe the problem in detail.

Comment: In the future, should I or someone else "wrongfully" fail an audit again, should I post to meta to try and get my review restriction lifted, or should I just accept it and wait? What would be the appropriate course of action?

Comment: If it is a blatantly wrong review audit, you can just include that you were banned from review in the flag message and we'll take care of it. You can always come to Meta if you are ever confused about whether you should have failed an audit or not.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with deleting the answer.  Sure, auxilliary information to another answer should be posted as a comment when possible... but comments can't contain images.  And there is no prohibition on answers than build on other answers.

Comment: @BenVoigt [An image alone is not an answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116050/using-only-an-image-as-an-answer) If you really feel that particular image is helpful, edit it into the other answer. Alone, it's useless and should be deleted.

Comment: @animuson: That meta post is completely inapplicable to the situation here.  A picture of UI with a particular portion of the UI highlighted is not the same as a scanned image of explanatory text.

Comment: How is it not? An image is still an image. And without an explanation, it is still unsearchable. The explanation is *already provided* in the other answer, and the user was only providing an image to complement that description. That is simply not an answer.

Comment: @animuson: Correct... it is a comment legitimately posted as an answer because the comment function doesn't support the needed formatting.  I've posted "answers" before which were really comments but included images, or multiline code or quotes, or were simply too long for a comment.  Not often, but when I do they are always welcomed.

Comment: We have a long history of relaxing the rules for answers to permit comments that are good comments and require the advanced formatting permitted in answers.

Comment: @Ben If it's not an answer then it shouldn't be posted as an answer. Like I said, if  you truly believe it's useful to also provide an image that demonstrates where, edit it into the existing answer where the formatting exists. Posting only an image as an answer is never appropriate.

Comment: I edited the picture from the deleted question into the high-quality, accepted answer on the question. Was this a good move? (My edits are still peer-reviewed, so someone with more editing experience than me will double-check my edit anyway.)

Comment: @Kevin I'm not a mod, and I don't really have sway here, but I'd say that improving the accepted answer is always a good practice (as this is a QA repository). If that iae can be helpful to someone in the future, and it makes the answer better, it's worth keeping.

Comment: It seems like time-wasting to edit that deleted answer and move the image into the other answer. If the image was ultimately useful enough to actually take it and place it into the top answer, then clearly the secondary answer was useful enough to avoid being deleted.

Comment: @BenVoigt if I do the "strip markdown and check if it still answer the question" test, that post inequivocally fails. It was rightly deleted as their content isn't self-contained.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't the mere fact that someone migrated the image from the deleted answer into the accepted answer mean, unequivocally, that the now-deleted answer was useful all along? If that image serves a useful purpose in the accepted answer, then it surely served a useful purpose posted as a secondary answer? In fact, for users without enough rep to consider placing the image directly into the answer via an edit, the best possible way they could bring a useful image to the attention of other users is to place it in an answer of their own. That it was ultimately considered useful enough to migrate it into the accepted answer (and that [describing this action was upvoted at least 3 times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280764/is-this-really-a-high-quality-answer?cb=1#comment132532_280765)) suggests to me that the original image-containing answer was a useful service to the community that should have been upvoted and left alone (possibly even in addition to duplicating the image into the accepted answer).

Maybe I am way off base, but this seems like a colossal waste of time. The secondary answer wasn't the greatest thing ever, but it was created in the spirit of adding useful extra info that the existing answer (at that time) did not contain. People found it useful (so useful, in fact, that after its deletion people took it upon themselves to reproduce that content into the accepted answer, and other people upvoted them for stating that they took that action).

If we're going to flag things for deletion, why not prioritize things that are actually of low quality -- spam, nonsense etc. I don't see why it was useful, time-wise, to delete this post. Even if there is some sort of long-run signal-to-noise benefit to it, it is surely swamped out by the short term time-loss for the review and this meta post. Probably the entire discounted future "value" of the minute improvement of signal-to-noise will not ever sum up to as much as the lost value to wasted time spent on this kind of thing in meta.

Comment: Links can also be useful, but answers which only consist of links are still not considered answers. Similarly, an image, whether useful or not, **is not an answer**. Plain and simple.

Comment: I disagree entirely -- I also think the equivocation between links and images is a false one. An image can depict an explanation. For example, if I don't know where a certain setting lives in a menu in a certain program, an image (with no textual explanation whatsoever) would be a very efficient and good answer. A link is different in that it does not, in an autological way, describe the problem it is addressing. It has to be clicked an evaluated external to itself to extract info. That's quite different than an image which directly exposes the solution.

Comment: I also feel that we should strive for a more common sense approach to whatever adds value for community users. Not whatever is someone's interpretation of the "letter of the law" so to speak. That the guidelines might say something about "answers not consisting of solely a link" means literally nothing to me (possibly less than nothing) because it is not related to curating items of value. In cases when a link-only answer clearly adds value (say by having many up-votes) it's nonsense to then delete it just because some string of characters somewhere else says to.

Comment: They are very equivocal. An image in itself **is** a link. An image by itself with no description to supplement it is not a good answer. I agree an image can be useful in depicting where something is located, **as long as there is text that also describes its location**. There are plenty of people and networks that flat-out block Imgur. So that answer, containing only the image and nothing else, is 100% useless to someone behind a block like that - the epitome of not an answer. I suggested editing it into the other answer because the textual description was already there; no repetition needed.

Comment: It's also useless for visually impaired people too. But it's also *useful* to a whole bunch of others.

Comment: That's exactly my point. If you provide a textual description, then screen readers can read text to a visually impaired person. Images are for **supplemental demonstration only** and should never be the sole piece of an answer.

Comment: I hear your point -- I am just saying I disagree with it. **Images are not for supplemental demonstration only** (I can use bold letters to make baseless statements too :D) -- Images *can be used* as supplemental demonstration *but even if they are used as the sole content of an answer* that can be very valuable *to a wide range of community members, though not all* and thus should be encouraged and/or left alone when it serves that useful purpose.

Comment: Our quality standards say otherwise, and I will gladly delete any image-only answers I see as they are not real answers.

Comment: You call them quality standards, I call them anti-quality standards. I will continue to whine on meta any time I see this mindless adherence to "standards" destroying value and wasting time.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Aside from the image issue, surely one cohesive, correct answer is better for future readers than the full answer being split into two "answers"? I dislike rule pedantry myself, but I think there's a good reason for tidying this particular situation up. Improvement of existing answers is actively encouraged, and correcting this to how it should have been done in the first place seems to me to simply be upholding that aspect of the site. (Both as a direct fix, and hopefully indirectly as a demonstration of how to approach such a situation.)

Comment: As far as the image issue, it's reasonable to ask that images are accompanied by explanatory text. Blocking of images and accessibility for the disabled are both good reasons which have nothing to do with mindless adherence to rules, and in both cases show how the text _does_ add value. That said I think it would be a shame if someone outright deleted a useful image, removing that information from the site - but that hasn't happened in this case. There's a reasonable midpoint behind deleting all image-only answers regardless of worth and just leaving them as-is.

Comment: @JoDouglass I disagree about the one-cohesive-answer idea. Many, if not most, of the SO questions/answers that I personally find most valuable are not fully answered with only a single accepted answer. More often there are multiple highly valuable answers from different people, sometimes with overlapping information, sometimes fully orthogonal to each other. Putting them into one cohesive answer would not alter the value provided in a meaningful way in most cases, and the variety of perspectives that is encouraged by allowing for multiple answers is more useful overall than incenting just one.

Comment: @JoDouglass I'm not arguing that (images + text) are *worse* than (just images). I'm arguing that (just images) are better than (no answer / no contribution because it was deleted due to being 'just an image'). That is, "just images," imperfect as they are, still do add value, and can often answer a question usefully without needing accompanying text. That would be a good reason to edit that answer and add text yourself -- but not a good reason to *delete that answer and thus destroy the value it added.* "Just images" are targets for improvement, not deletion.

Comment: Obviously this is all under the ceteris paribus assumption that the image is contextually relevant to the question. A nonsense image, or inappropriate image, etc., would of course be deleted like any other non-answer post.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr I'd agree with you if the answers were complete answers or fundamentally different answers, but not in this scenario. The deleted "answer" wasn't a complete answer, it was illustrating something from the earlier answer in order to add more information - it was improving the earlier answer rather than adding an alternate one. Left alone, that leaves two partial "answers" which is less useful than forming them into a cohesive whole.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr I tend towards the improve-not-delete mindset myself, but then I'm too new here to get to make those decisions for real, yet. ;) I believe one of the concerns is that being too "soft" on this sort of issue does nothing to discourage people who are posting low-effort answers hoping for up-votes, and potentially undermines the overall site quality. On the other hand, losing information and scaring off users who could have learnt to be worthwhile contributors seem like valid concerns as well. I don't think **this specific case** is concerning, but do understand the wider issue.