# What happened to review bans?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, review-suspension

Over the past few weeks, I've noticed that audits are showing up more frequently, but that the consequences are not as severe. This may just be me (there are those who swear that this doesn't happen to them), but before this, I could pass 15-20 audits in a row only to fail one and be banned.

[There's a general agreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272472/better-review-audits-better-review-ban-tools) that the audit system could use some improvements, but I've been a proponent of easing up on the banning a little (although I really do think the community managers - or whoever planned this bit (there's a Meta post somewhere that I can't find) - did a great job deciding on the incremental increase of ban periods and the system works fairly well).

Again, this doesn't happen to everyone, but I feel that we should get more than one chance to prove our review competence (especially with [all of the edge cases out there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits)). In these seemingly new conditions, I've failed two or three audits without being banned.

Did something change, or am I going crazy?

---

I'm told that [nothing is going on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281459/3366929), but it seems they've flipped the switch back on if it was ever off (and they flipped it hard); I haven't failed an audit in a few weeks, but after I failed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6744468), I was banned for a month.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Several possibilities, listed in decreasing order of probability:

1. **You're getting lucky.** Audits are shown randomly; perhaps you're seeing fewer of them? It doesn't matter how many you pass, just how many you fail - and if you're getting fewer audits, you have less of a chance of failing as often.
2. **You're getting slower.** Review bans are much more likely if you aren't spending much time on each review task. Note that I said "review **task**" not "audit" - if you're blazing through normal reviews, it doesn't matter how much time you spend on that audit; if you fail it, you're much more likely to get banned. Perhaps you finally learned to take your time and read the posts you're reviewing?
3. **You're getting better.** At reviewing, that is - but not at remembering your reviews. Perhaps you actually are failing fewer audits and just forgot about all the ones you're passing?

Comment: Hmm...maybe. I thought for sure that the SE team had changed something, but I wasn't aware of a couple of those factors.

Comment: Does the number of reviews, or bans take into account how often someone reviews a item in a way that is different from most other reviewers?

Comment: The automatic bans don't, @Ian. Moderators can.

Answer (score 9):

I agree, something has changed. I could fail 1-2 before and get banned, now it
seems more relaxed. I also agree with Shog9, I am getting better, but in a
backhanded sort of way. As has been noted

[Is this really a high-quality answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280764)

The review system has some problems. You can review a post negatively that you
genuinely feel is crap, but if the algorithm does not agree with you then you
fail. In addition the system tricks you by anonymizing the user, lowering their
reputation significantly and lowering the score of the question/answer.

Sadly I have found that the best way to do reviews is to look at the actual
question/answer. So for every single review I click the link to actual content,
and if it does not match (deleted/not deleted; closed/not closed) then I know it
is a test.