# What is the formal process for lifting a review ban?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359255/python-match-and-parse-strings-containing-numeric-currency-amounts) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593687/implementing-a-language-in-haskell-dynamic-typing-for-polymorphic-functions) should not be used as audits.

What is the current process for requesting a lift from a ban from a bad audit?

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/175248

Comment: Related: [Lifting the Review Ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351446/lifting-the-review-ban)

Comment: @Makoto I don't see where that answers this question

Comment: You should first prove it's a bad audit by following the guidelines upon encountering an audit that you disagree with.  Post it here and draw attention to it and *then* moderators can decide to take action.

Comment: @DavyM That question only show's how that user got his ban lifted, it does not entail the formal process for requesting a lift on any ban

Comment: For the record: I reviewed Johnny's review actions before when they were banned, and both then and this time the ban was unjust and the audit wrong. Bad luck, twice.

Comment: @Johnny5 That's why I said related and not dupe. Though he's doing it right, as the answer below states.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you so much again! The reviews have been not so nice to me.

Comment: @Makoto: better uber-meta dupe? [How to contest a review ban?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/284598)

Comment: Careful Johnny I've asked similar questions. People don't take kindly to questioning the review process I've found. The fact that the solution requires a moderator to review (multiple?) separate meta posts on a case-by-case basis to handle the situation tells me that the process could be improved. But I seem to be in the minority.

Comment: @JacobH:  That's because it happens so sparingly.  In spite of what you may think, contested review bans are a rare occurrence.

Comment: @Makoto,  I think there are a lot more cases in which the audit system fails, but most people doing reviews, aren't doing it with intentions of becoming moderators in the future, so if they are banned they just accept it.  I've only started disputing my bans when I found out unhelig was banned for a year

Comment: Basically what I've gathered is "It was worse before so don't question it now". Notice how this post is gathering downvotes for apparently no reason? Even though making the post *IS* the recommended Answer-- I.E. make a post regarding the ban. Q.E.D. To be honest, I take a bigger issue with the fact that people who are trying to help with moderation are seemingly arbitrarily limited or audited/banned and required to go out of their way to follow this (undocumented) process to "repair" their reputation. It's almost like SO doesn't *want* users to help.

Answer (score 8):

You're using it. It's called Meta.SO

Post your review audit links with the tags [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280764/is-this-really-a-high-quality-answer))

If a moderator agrees with you they can lift the review ban.